# How to handle exception Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How to handle exception Exception java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB. Marshmallow permission for Phone state required.but when the client rejected 4-5 times.

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull 
 String[] 
    permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CaptureInfoApiCall();
        } else {

 marshmallowPermission.isCheckReadPhoneStatePermission(HomeScreen.this);
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == 3) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startService(new Intent(HomeScreen.this,
                LocationService.class));
        } else {
            marshmallowPermission.ischeckLocationPermission(HomeScreen.this);
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: please give the CatLogs

Comment: Is the StackOverflowError occurring inside this method or  - more likely - occurring inside some recursive call which invokes this method? Showing the stack trace for the SOE would help here.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the app it may not be friendly but better than the error take a look at this code let us know if it helps

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //.... write file into storage ...
            System.out.println("SDK > BuildVersion TRUE");
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 666);  // Comment 26
            System.out.println("go to requestPermissions");
        }
    }
    onLoad();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 666: // Allowed was selected so Permission granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Permission Granted",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = s.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextSize(18);
                textView.setMaxLines(6);
                s.show();

                // do your work here

            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                // User selected the Never Ask Again Option Change settings in app settings manually
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Change Permissions in Settings");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click SETTINGS to Manually Set\n\n"+"Permissions to use Database Storage")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);     // Comment 3.
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            } else {
                    // User selected Deny Dialog to EXIT App ==> OR <== RETRY to have a second chance to Allow Permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Second Chance");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click RETRY to Set Permissions to Allow\n\n"+"Click EXIT to the Close App")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Integer.parseInt(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    finish();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }};
```